# how to find the longest title in a list of dict and print the name and how many characters the title has on python?

Tags: python, max

I'm starting to learn some coding and I am stuck on how to solve this with python. I have a list of dict that I have to go through and print the longest movie title and the integer length of the title.

So far I can print the length (the wrong film though), but the title recognises "y" as the highest value more than printing the full name.

```
def get_max_movie_name_length():
  for length in movies:
    title = length["title"]
  for name in movies:
    film_title = name["title"]
  return [max(film_title), len(title)]

get_max_movie_name_length()
```

the list:

```
[{'title': 'The Shawshank Redemption'},
 {'title': 'The Godfather'},
 {'title': 'The Dark Knight'},
 {'title': 'The Godfather: Part II'}]
```

the answer would be something like "The Shawshank Redemption" "24"
thank you

Answer (score 2):

You just need the builtin `max` function with the right `key` argument to compare list elements.

```
>>> lst = [{'title': 'The Shawshank Redemption'},
...  {'title': 'The Godfather'},
...  {'title': 'The Dark Knight'},
...  {'title': 'The Godfather: Part II'}]
>>> max(lst, key=lambda x: len(x['title']))
{'title': 'The Shawshank Redemption'}
>>> longest_title_show = max(lst, key=lambda x: len(x['title']))
>>> len(longest_title_show['title'])
24
```

Comment: upvoted, but for someone who is having trouble looping over and comparing lengths, `max` function may be too much magic. A simple, boring `for` loop would do and make things painfully obvious.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to loop through the list of dictionaries to find the movie with the longest title. You can keep track of the maximum length and the corresponding movie title while iterating through the list.

Here's the corrected code:

```
def get_max_movie_name_length(movies):
    max_length = 0
    max_title = ""

    for movie in movies:
        title = movie["title"]
        if len(title) > max_length:
            max_length = len(title)
            max_title = title

    return max_title, max_length

movies = [
    {'title': 'The Shawshank Redemption'},
    {'title': 'The Godfather'},
    {'title': 'The Dark Knight'},
    {'title': 'The Godfather: Part II'}
]

longest_movie_title, title_length = get_max_movie_name_length(movies)
print("Longest movie title:", longest_movie_title)
print("Title length:", title_length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid solutions have already been offered - I want to expound on why your approach doesn't work.

You have a for-loop, that iterates over each "movie object" (each dictionary represents one movie):

`for length in movies:`

What you're calling `length` is one movie object, or one dictionary. `length` isn't a good name. Why not call it what it is, namely `movie`? I digress, for each iteration of this loop, you do:

`title = length["title"]`

On the first iteration, you're creating a variable named `title`, and you're binding the current movie's title to that variable. Then, in the next iteration of the loop, you're rebinding the `title` variable to point at the next movie's title. This continues until you've iterated over all movie objects, and when the loop is done, `title` will be pointing at the last movie's title. So, basically this loop doesn't do anything useful, and it certainly isn't doing what you intended.

It's a similar story for the second for-loop. What you're calling `name` is a movie object/single dictionary. `movie` would be a better name. Again, you are iterating over the collection of movies, first creating a new variable `film_title` and then rebinding it to point at the next movie's title. By the time this loop is done, `film_title` will be pointing at the last movie's title, just like `title`. Neither of these loops do what you want.

In other words, when both loops are done, your variables will be pointing at:

```
title => 'The Godfather: Part II'
film_title => 'The Godfather: Part II'
```

They are bound to the string `'The Godfather: Part II'`, because that's the title of the last movie in your collection of movies.

Then, you return a list, where the first element is `max(film_title)`.

This is equivalent to `max('The Godfather: Part II')`. When you pass a string into the built-in `max`, it will compare the characters lexicographically - according to the order in which they appear in the ASCII table. For example, a simple test in the Python shell:

```
>>>max('abc')
'c'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.. It makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score -2):

I would make a tuple of `(len(title), title)` for each item in the list. Next, sort the list of tuples (by default a tuple will be sorted by the first element, thus the length). Finally, take the last element of the sorted list.

You can do that in a single line with list comprehension:

```
data = [
    {'title': 'The Shawshank Redemption'},
    {'title': 'The Godfather'},
    {'title': 'The Dark Knight'},
    {'title': 'The Godfather: Part II'}
]

longest = sorted([(len(v), v) for d in data for v in d.values()])[-1]
print(longest) #(24, 'The Shawshank Redemption')
```

As pointed out, using max would be a better choice.

```
longest = max([(len(v), v) for d in data for v in d.values()])
```

Comment: Sorting the list is completely unnecessary and slow. Finding the max is an `O(n)` operation, but sorting makes it `O(n log n)`.

Comment: It is slower than max, yes. Still, it is the first solution that came to mind, and it is correct. Plus, given the input, I doubt it will matter in practice. If the OP had asked what is the most efficient way to do it for a list of a million items, then ok. Said that, I agree that @Chris answer is better than mine. But I don't think I deserve a downvote.

Comment: Sorting the list to find max is certainly not the first thing that comes to mind, because there's a trivial and better solution. Thus, it's not only a question of efficiency, but doing redundant work that is confusing to a newbie who is having trouble with a simple `for` loop.

Comment: Ok. I agree. It is redundant. I have added the max option as well.